# ActiveRecord::QueryCanceled: PG::QueryCanceled: ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout when query Ahoy Event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a query like this with `Ahoy` gem:

```rb
Ahoy::Event.where_event('Ran action').group_by_week(:time).where_props(
  event_id: current_event.id
).count
```

but get error message like below:

```
ActiveRecord::QueryCanceled: PG::QueryCanceled: ERROR:  canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

I'm thinking it because the database is too big so it take too long to query. I have used `find_in_batches` to fix but it seem to be not the right path.

I'm very bad at SQL so this is really a headache. Any help is appreciate.

Comment: Check your `log/development.log` to see what query is being run. A timeout usually means it took too long to finish.

Comment: You could debug by reducing chaining query methods, start from `Ahoy::Event.where_event('Ran action').count`, to see which query method breaks.

Comment: It break at ```group_by_week(:time)``` with error ```ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "ahoy_events.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)``` @eux

Comment: The you could try `Ahoy::Event.group_by_week(:time).count` to see if it works, if it works then the two query methods may can't be used at the same time.